# how to monitor when the iPhone has conneted to the car bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

how can I know when the user get in the car (When the IOS device conect to any paired car) and when the user get out of the car ( When IOS device disconnect from any paired car ).

I dicovered that it is possible by going to "Reminders" on my iPhone and setting a reminder then going to "details" and press "Remind me at a location" and then I have the option to select "Getting in the car" or "getting out of the car".

It works well on my car with no CarPlay set. It seems that iOS system just monitoring the connected/disconnected events of car bluetooth(classic bluetooth, BLE is not required).

Is there any APIs that I can use to develop my own app? when users get in their car, my app can be notified by the system and do some task I defined?